# SVG masks, using one shape's coordinates to partially mark another shape

Tags: svg, path, mask

I have a series of opaque svg paths that overlap eachother. I want to create a mask based on each shape's previous sibling to mask the overlap.

My problem is that in a case where I have to shapes (fiddle below) the mask based on shape 0 completely removes shape 1

I'm a bit new at SVG, but it was my understanding that the mask "punches a hole" in its coordinates when applied. I expected the mask to remove anything in shape 1 that shares coordinates with shape 0, not completely hiding it. What am I doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/nazhgvL6/3/

```
<svg pointer-events="none" width="1558" height="1163" viewBox="-130 -97 1558 1163" style="transform: translate3d(-330px, -497px, 0px) scale(1);">

  <defs>
  <!-- #mask-shape-1 d attribute is the same as the d attribute of the shape 0 path-->
    <mask id="mask-shape-1"> <!-- rename ID to turn mask on/off -->
      <path d="M779 780L779 767L775 741L771 728L760 704L746 682L737 672L717 655L682 636L656 629L630 627L604 636L582 648L563 664L555 673L543 692L529 709L515 737L510 758L508 779L516 799L526 817L539 831L562 847L571 862L592 881L601 887L619 895L630 898L650 897L670 891L689 883L707 871L714 864L733 852L742 844L757 826L764 816L775 792z" fill="white"></path>
      <path d="M779 780L779 767L775 741L771 728L760 704L746 682L737 672L717 655L682 636L656 629L630 627L604 636L582 648L563 664L555 673L543 692L529 709L515 737L510 758L508 779L516 799L526 817L539 831L562 847L571 862L592 881L601 887L619 895L630 898L650 897L670 891L689 883L707 871L714 864L733 852L742 844L757 826L764 816L775 792z" rx="5" fill="black"></path>"
    </mask>

  </defs>

  <g>
  <!-- shape 0 -->
    <path class="arrival-lines-polygon-fill leaflet-interactive" stroke="none" fill="red" fill-opacity="0.2" d="M779 780L779 767L775 741L771 728L760 704L746 682L737 672L717 655L682 636L656 629L630 627L604 636L582 648L563 664L555 673L543 692L529 709L515 737L510 758L508 779L516 799L526 817L539 831L562 847L571 862L592 881L601 887L619 895L630 898L650 897L670 891L689 883L707 871L714 864L733 852L742 844L757 826L764 816L775 792z" mask="url(#mask-shape-0)"></path>

  <!-- shape 1 -->
    <path class="arrival-lines-polygon-fill leaflet-interactive" stroke="none" fill="red" fill-opacity="0.2" d="M562 849L522 810L495 770L485 749L482 738L483 715L489 693L498 671L504 661L541 613L573 588L599 576L614 572L643 575L657 578L684 588L697 595L709 603L731 622L749 644L756 656L768 683L772 696L777 731L779 760z" mask="url(#mask-shape-1)"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: The second path have fill="black"

Comment: @enxaneta If we look at MDN's example, the fill="black" seem to turn the masked content to invisible, changing it doesn't really do much except change the color inside the mask. https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/ Do you think the black fill does harm to the result?

Comment: I think you want `clip-path`, not `mask`. You can read about the difference at https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/ . A `clip-path` is a path, and a mask is a bitmap (which in turn may be defined as a path). The fill of a `clip-path` is not important, the fill of a `mask` is very important.

Comment: @vqf Clip path is made to cut off content outside of the defined path, but with mask I can try to define an area where a fill won't be shown. After looking in to the issue I think this is a two sided issue with the library Leaflet which i'm using, and how one programatically add svg stuff.